# Display property ignores background color of navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I have a simple navigation bar, I wanted the last 3 items to be on the right so i used the span element to do that.However, they were turning into block level elements ofcourse, because li are block-level elements.However, when i set the property `display: inline;`
The whole background color of my navigation bar disappeared.Here's the full code

```css
.navBar{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: rgb(0,124,96);
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.right-content{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navBar">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <span class="right-content">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
    </span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I also have one question, I couldn't use the `text-align: right;`
on my span element, why is that?

Comment: You really shouldn't have anything other than `li` as direct descendants of the `ul` element.

Comment: So the span element conflicts?

Comment: Well `span` inside of `ul` is invalid HTML. Because of that, you will likely encounter unexpected behavior.

Comment: How I learned span was that it acts the same as a div but is just an inline element.That is why I thought it would work.

Comment: Yeah, but `ul` is a special element. There are a few elements like this. It is best to use an HTML validator (i.e. validator.w3.org) to ensure that the code you write is valid. Valid HTML yields more predictable behavior across platforms. It would be much more appropriate to just add a class to each of the `li` items you want on the right and address them directly, or split it into two different lists and surround the lists in a `nav` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers have invalid HTML with a `span` as a child of a `ul`. I've re-written this to omit the invalid HTML.

The `.navBar:after { ... }` stuff is just to ensure that the surrounding navBar height includes the floated elements, should they yield line-wrapping or something based on the screen size.

```css
.navBar{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: rgb(0,124,96);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navBar:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.navBar li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.navBar li.aside {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navBar">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="aside">
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li class="aside">
      <a href="#">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li class="aside">
      <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the inline display style to the `li`s not to the `ul`(`.navBar`):

```css
.navBar{
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: rgb(0,124,96);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navBar li {
  display:inline;
}
.right-content{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <ul class="nav navBar">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <span class="right-content">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
    </span>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Shaw text-align will align the text within the span, meaning it will align the text to the right side of the span, but the span itself won't align to the right.

Comment: Using `span` inside an `ul` like this is still asking for trouble. That is invalid / non-compliant HTML, and can/will result in unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Text-align doesn't work on a `span`, because a `span` is never wider than the containing text, unless you add `display:block` or `display:inline-block` and a `width` to it.

However, you don't need to use `span` here. Simply set the `li` elements to `inline-block` .

```
.navBar li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
background:transparent;
    }
```

The reason why your background color isn't showing on the `ul`, is because using `float` (and I think also `inline`, but am not sure there) causes the `ul` to collapse to 0 height. Hence, you must add `height` to it in your stylesheet.

```
.navBar{
        height:50px;
        list-style-type: none;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 30px;
        background: rgb(0,124,96);
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

edit: to make the `li` elements not touch each other, you can set a margin:

```
.navBar li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
background:transparent;
margin-right:5px;
    }
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nax0qhL4/) with all of it together.

Comment: All `float` elements are taken out of the flow of content and don't contribute to the height.